# Problema con las rutas en PHP

Tags: php, linux, mvc, xampp

Tengo un problema con las rutas (creo) ya que estoy trabajando con *Xampp* en *Windows* y el proyecto me funciona bien, pero al momento del subirlo a un hosting, me marca un error:

> **Fatal error:** Class '\App\Controllers\Home' not found in **/home/liftechc/public_html/rrhh/Core/App.php** on line **53**

---

El archivo **App.php** contiene este fragmento de código:

```
/**
* @var
*/
const NAMESPACE_CONTROLLERS = "\App\Controllers\\";

/**
 * @var
 */
const CONTROLLERS_PATH = "../App/controllers/";

/**
 * [__construct description]
 */
public function __construct() {
    //obtenemos la url parseada
    $url = $this->parseUrl();

    //Comprobamos que exista el archivo en el directorio controllers.
    if(file_exists(self::CONTROLLERS_PATH . ucfirst($url[0]) . ".php")) {
        //nombre del archivo a llamar
        $this->_controller = ucfirst($url[0]);
        //eliminamos el controlador de url,
        // así sólo nos quedarán los parámetros del método
        unset($url[0]);
    } else {
        include APPPATH . "/views/errors/404.php";
        exit;
    }
    //Obtenemos la clase con su espacio de nombres.
    $fullClass = self::NAMESPACE_CONTROLLERS . $this->_controller;

    //Asociamos la instancia a $this->_controller
    $this->_controller = new $fullClass; <--- ESTA ES LA LINEA 53, DONDE ME DA EL ERROR!

    //Si existe el segundo segmento comprobamos que el método exista en esa clase.
    if(isset($url[1])) {

        //aquí tenemos el método
        $this->_method = $url[1];
        if(method_exists($this->_controller, $url[1])) {
            //Eliminamos el método de url,
            // así sólo nos quedarán los parámetros del método.
            unset($url[1]);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Error Processing Method {$this->_method}", 1);
        }
    }
    //Asociamos el resto de segmentos a $this->_params
    // para pasarlos al método llamado, por defecto será un array vacío.
    $this->_params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
}
```

---

El archivo **index.php** contiene este código:

```
//Borrar para produccion
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Sesion
session_start();

//URL
define("DIR_URL", "http://localhost/rrhh2/public/");
//define("DIR_URL", "http://sitios-en-desarrollo.com/rrhh/public/");

//Directorio del proyecto.
define("PROJECTPATH", dirname(__DIR__));

//Directorio app
define("APPPATH", PROJECTPATH . '/App');

//autoload con namespaces
function autoload_classes($class_name) {
    $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    if(is_file($filename)) {
        include_once $filename;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload_classes'); //Registramos el autoload autoload_classes
$app = new \Core\App; //Instanciamos la app
$app->render(); //Lanzamos la app
```

Comment: El error se origina en el autoloader que tienes en el index. Está buscando el archivo [proyecto]/App/Controllers/Home.php ¿Existe el archivo? Debe contener la clase Home dentro del namespace App\Controllers ¿Es así?

Comment: asi tal cual esta, y asi me corre muy bien en xampp, el error lo marca es en ser hosting...

Comment: No estás usando composer para el proyecto?

Comment: Y en el hosting, ¿el controlador tiene el nombre correcto `Home.php` (con la H mayúscula)? Si estuviera en minúscula, no daría problemas en Windows (xampp) pero sí en Linux (hosting).

Comment: no estoy usando composer, si los archivos controladores están con la primera letra en mayúscula. el codigo que estoy usando, lo saque de esta página: https://www.uno-de-piera.com/desarrolla-tu-propio-mvc-con-php-y-poo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En __construct() haces **file_exists** con:

```
const CONTROLLERS_PATH = "../App/controllers/";
```

cuando chequeas si existe el archivo, te dice que si xq la carpeta "controllers" esta en minuscula.

```
../App/controllers/Home.php
```

---

En la funcion "autoload_classes" haces **is_file** con el nombre de la clase construido con:

```
const NAMESPACE_CONTROLLERS = "\App\Controllers\\";
```

ahi, la palabra "Controllers" esta con la primera letra en Mayuscula

"autoload_classes" solo cambia las barras del Namespace por Separador de directorios, pero ejecuta is_file con:

```
../App/Controllers/Home.php
```

que no existe....

Linux es case-sensitive.

---

Espero haber ayudado esta vez....

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/33469)

Comment: Tienes razon. Ya corregi, espero haber ayudado.

Comment: a mí me parece que esta es la respuesta correcta